# Use binary prefixes in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I know the difference between decimal and binary prefixes (KB vs KiB), and it's really annoying to see Windows displaying decimal prefixes for files or disks sizes when it calculates them using powers of 1024. Plus, is should be a lower-case "k" for "kilo", [according to the SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix).

So, is there a way to force it to display binary prefixes (and possibly a "k" for "kilo") ? I don't care if I need to "hack" some system files for that. My specific case is about Windows 7, but if you have answers for other versions it's also good to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option or hack to change the way File Explorer, Task Manager, etc., display amounts of memory, file sizes, etc. These programs just don't have that code in them. (If you patched the executables, then sure... then you'd have to sign your new exe's in a manner compatible with Code Integrity services... or disable that... have fun!)

The best you could do would be to use other utility programs than Windows Explorer, etc., programs that do use the IEC binary prefixes with powers of 1024. And presumably you'd want them to use the SI prefixes and powers of 1000 for disk sizes (since that's how disks are marketed).

I don't know of any programs that do this out of the box. But there is a replacement for File Explorer called Explorer++. It has source available and so could be modified to do this.

To replace Task Manager you could use Process Hacker - for which source is also available.

This would not, of course, do anything about the myriad other programs within Windows. Disk Management, for example, would continue to show drive, partition, and volume sizes using multiples of powers of 1024 but with SI prefixes. but Explorer++ and Process Hacker would cover a lot of what most people look at most of the time in this area.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to change the prefixes to be correct. I actually don't think the code to format units is in each executable, but more likely in a common library that the whole OS uses (such as a DLL), seeing as Windows uses the prefixes consistently incorrectly. This might help your case if you're trying to hack the files, as there will only be one location where you'd have to change this, but like Jamie says, I think getting the code signed would be challenging.

Another easy way to "force" this is through the old fashioned way: report to them to fix this error by upvoting feedback in the Feedback Hub app such as the one entitled "SI prefixes for information sizes".